# Odoo 13 : how to allow field to be editable in form builder

Tags: odoo

I want to allow field to be editable in form builder,
I added "title" field in a custom odoo form (contact form), but it shouldn't in website_form_blacklised, so I wrote this code :

```
class CrmLead(models.Model):
    _inherit = "crm.lead"
    title = fields.Many2one(website_form_blacklisted=False)
```

But it doesn't work,
Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved, I added this in xml,

```
<function model="ir.model.fields" name="formbuilder_whitelist">
        <value>crm.lead</value>
        <value eval="[
            'title'
        ]"/>
    </function>
```